# Glimpse for MVC3 module not found after NuGet install of Glimpse.MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I just added Glimpse.MVC3 to an MVC3 app I'm battling to deploy to IIS / debug on IIS (7.5), but when I try to activate it via Glimpse.axd, I get a 404 not found.  I am appending the url to my route, and no longer attempting it as an absolute url

Comment: Can you copy your web.config into your question?

Comment: While preparing a smaller example I had success with the example, so I'll work back from there to my larger, dysfunctional Glimpse target.

Comment: Sounds good ProfK, I'll keep an eye on this page just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through this:  http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration

In web.config make sure it is enabled

`<glimpse enabled="true" loggingEnabled="true" requestLimit="15">`

IP Addresses ...

```
<ipAddresses>
<add address="127.0.0.1" />
<add address="192.168.100.59" />
<add address="::1" />
<add address="fe80::f17e:d177:359f:6cee%14" />
</ipAddresses>
```

Comment: 404 errors fixed! Goodbye /Glimpse/Config, hello /Glimpse.axd  The short version, is that /Glimpse/Config is being deprecated and being replaced with /Glimpse.axd

Comment: forgive me for being somewhat wary, but you say 'make sure it is enabled', and your config example has two 'false' values for 'enabled', and isn't a 'pluginBlacklist' for plugins you *don't* want?  Then to get back to my question, it's with /Glimpse.axd I'm getting the 404.

Comment: I must have pasted the wrong line.  Sorry...  set Enabled to true, requestlimit is for Ajax and Remote tabs and thus how many request are stored.  loggingenabled set to true ... It is for internal debugging.   Yes, make sure that you don't blacklist a plugin that you don't want.  That is what I get for copy and paste ....  So Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the module is registered properly in your web.config, remember you will set it up differently in classic vs integrated mode.

You also need to delpoy Glimpse.Core.dll to your applications bin directory.

Comment: I don't know what properly registered is, but it's there just as NuGet put it there, and it is most definitely in my bin directory, next to Glimpse.MVC3

Comment: Does your server have .NET 4 installed?

Comment: Yes, brand new VS 2010 and MVC3 installation, and I've re-registered .NET 4 with IIS.