# Installed glimpse attempting to access glimpse.axd and receive 404 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, glimpse

It is a simple as that I installed glimpse following this page. :

http://getglimpse.com/About/QuickStart

I then attempt to navigate to `http://myApp/glimpse.axd` and receive 404 error not found.

As you can see in the Quickstart there is this statement. :

If you get a "Page not found" when browsing to "/glimpse.axd" check the troubleshooting section in the FAQ.

There is nothing in the FAQ regarding this.  I have skimmed this website and getGlimpse.com attempting numerous other configurations and nothing is working.  Any one else run into this issue and fix it?

Tried this also. :

[Glimpse for MVC3 module not found after NuGet install of Glimpse.MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668914/glimpse-for-mvc3-module-not-found-after-nuget-install-of-glimpse-mvc3)

Comment: > Same problem. Work for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179655/how-to-use-glimpse-in-orchard-cms

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you have the Glimpse module and handler registered in your web.config based on the web server you are using.

- If you are using a site on IIS6, in IIS7.x classic pipeline mode or Visual Studio Development Server

  ```
  <system.web>
      <httpModules>
          <add 
              name="Glimpse" 
              type="Glimpse.Core.Module, Glimpse.Core"
          />
      </httpModules>
      <httpHandlers>
          <add 
              path="glimpse.axd" 
              verb="GET,POST" 
              type="Glimpse.Core.Handler, Glimpse.Core"
          />
     </httpHandlers>
     ...
  ```
- And if you are using IIS 7.x in integrated pipeline mode or IIS Express:

  ```
  <system.webServer>
      <modules>
          <add 
              name="Glimpse" 
              type="Glimpse.Core.Module, Glimpse.Core" 
              preCondition="integratedMode" 
          />
      </modules>
      <handlers>
          <add 
              name="Glimpse" 
              path="glimpse.axd" 
              verb="GET,POST" 
              type="Glimpse.Core.Handler, Glimpse.Core" 
              preCondition="integratedMode" 
          />
      </handlers>
      ...
  </system.webServer>
  ```

Comment: Added that in as I did not have that and still receive a 404.0.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Did you enable glimpse in your web.config file using the `<glimpse enabled="true" />` custom configuration section? Also which web server are you using to test this? IIS or IIS Express in Visual Studio? Also make sure that the `Glimpse.Core` assembly is present in your `bin` folder. Normally that's all you need to enable Glimpse.

Comment: Yes, I enabled it in web.config.  Using IIS 7.5.  Glimpse.Core is in my bin folder.  Still unable to access .axd.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any more clues. This setup has always worked for me. Any chance you could send me a sample project exhibiting the problem?

Comment: I just got it to work in a standard project.  Thank you so much for your time these have all been great suggestions.  My issue I think is that I have a  solution with about 8 projects in it.......

Comment: I was able to get it to work in both MVC3 and MVC4 standard test projects.  I think when it does in install in my multi project solution it doesn't know where to put the files.

Comment: Got it working, my package manager console was hitting the incorrect project.  Your answers were dead on leading me to this conclusion.

Answer (score 21):

I encountered the same problem and in my case the solution was to add the following code to Application_Start() in the MvcApplication class:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: Bam that's it. But it's enough to let through only Glimpse.axd: `routes.IgnoreRoute("Glimpse.axd");`

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me too, Just make sure that the IgnoreRoute code above is the FIRST route, as we all know the order is very important.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a very similar problem, and none of these options helped me, but I did get it working. This is what I had to do:

I am using MVC 5, so make sure you have read [the latest config](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Configuration) for glimpse for the version you are using. I should have been using **Glimpse.AspNet** and not <strike>**Glimpse.Core**</strike>

My web config looks like this:

```
 <handlers>
    ....
    <remove name="Glimpse" />
    <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET"
         type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet"   
         preCondition="integratedMode" />  
</handlers>
<modules>
    ....
    <remove name="Glimpse" />
    <add name="Glimpse" 
         type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" 
         preCondition="integratedMode"/>    
</modules>
```

I am using IIS Express, Vs2015 and for some reason my *C:\Users\me\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config* got messed up, and had a special entry for Glimpse.

So I found and removed any entries with **Glimpse** in them (carefully, you might want to comment them out instead)

```
<application path="/Glimpse.axd" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="\path\to\extra\website" />
</application>
```

I think this may have happened from a really early version of glimpse been installed, and also something to do with the upgrade to MVC5,  but not 100% sure why...

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had a multi-project solution and was installing it from the Package Manager Console.  I found that installing it using the following command worked:

```
 PM> Install-Package -ProjectName <MyProject> Glimpse.MVC4
```

Of course you need to replace `<MyProject>` with your own project name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the web app is not deployed in root, so the url is:

```
http://localhost:54026/MyApp/glimpse.axd
```

Very obvious, but I'll leave this answer as a reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Install Glimpse.AspNet and it will fix the issue for you and also modify the web.config by adding the handler and module.