# attempting to access glimpse.axd and getting error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, glimpse

i've installed glimpse through console package manager by this
Install-Package Glimpse.EF6
Glimpse.EF6/1.6.5 is installed on system and added in preferences.
following 'http://getglimpse.com/Docs/' tutorial, when i try to access http://mylocalhost/Glimpse.axd it shows me error

"HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

searched for the solution and found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130668/installed-glimpse-attempting-to-access-glimpse-axd-and-receive-404-error).

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

this line is already there app-start. tried to add keys in web.config but that shows error

"Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated. "

using IIS express. any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: i turned off the custom errors and found this is the actual problem when i try to add those lines in web.config.

"Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load type 'Glimpse.Core.Module' from assembly 'Glimpse.Core'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Glimpse.Core.Module' from assembly 'Glimpse.Core'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Glimpse.Core.Module' from assembly 'Glimpse.Core'.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +39
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +37
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +65
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load type 'Glimpse.Core.Module' from assembly 'Glimpse.Core'.]
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +348
   System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit) +19
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +39
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +42
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +158
   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +950
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +82
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Glimpse.Core.Module' from assembly 'Glimpse.Core'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9955652
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254"

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Glimpse?
Do you have multiple projects in your solution? have a look here: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/132

Comment: yes i've reinstalled glimpse and yes i've got 2 project in my solution and  glimpse is already installed in both projects but no difference :(

Comment: What other Glimpse packages are installed, and what are their versions?

Comment: Glimpse.ADO version 1.7.3.0


Glimpse.Core version 1.8.6.0

Glimpse.EF6 version 1.6.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alright the glimpse.EF6 was not working so i un-installed it and installed glipmse.mvc5 and it worked like a charm.